# how Futures.addCallback guarantee the callback to be executed at the thread executing the future task?

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

code shown below:

```
final ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4));

final Callable<String> asyncTask = new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
    return TestFuture.computeResult();
    }
};

final int listSize = 10;

final List<ListenableFuture<String>> listenableFutures = Lists.newArrayListWithExpectedSize(listSize);
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    listenableFutures.add(executor.submit(asyncTask));
}

for (final ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture2 : listenableFutures) {
    Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture2, new FutureCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final String result) {
        System.out.println("callback success with " + result + " at " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Throwable thrown) {
        System.out.println("callback failed with " + thrown.getMessage());
    }
    });
}
```

I cannot figure out that HOW the callback is scheduled to be executed at the thread that will executing the `asyncTask`?

I can see that `Futures.addCallback` calls `addCallback(future, callback, MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());`, but I donnot know How MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor guarantee this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sameThreadExecutor()` just executes any `Runnable` that's passed to its `execute(Runnable)` method inline: that is, it simply calls `run()` on it. It does nothing related to threads at all. And the callback `Runnable`s are passed to their associated `Executor` on the same thread that executes the `asyncTask` because the `ListeningExecutorService` effectively wraps your `asyncTask` in a [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) that calls all callbacks when its `done()` method is called.

Note: it is *not* actually guaranteed that all of your callbacks will be executed on the thread that executes the `asyncTask`. For example, if you add a callback *after* the `asyncTask` has completed, it'll be executed on the thread that you added the callback on (assuming you don't provide an `Executor` other than `sameThreadExecutor()` for the callback to use).